# prettytables - dynamically refresh data in shell display?

Tags: python, shell, module

I'm building a bot that loops through various activities (as bots often do) and I'm using 'prettytables' to display the activity.

https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial

```
def promote(self):
    x = PrettyTable(["Bot ID", "Bot Name"])
    x.align["Bot ID"] = "l" # Left align city names
    x.padding_width = 1 # One space between column edges and contents (default)


    for bot_id, atts in self.bots.iteritems():               
            x.add_row([str(bot_id),atts['screenname']])

    print x
```

Ideally I'd like to loop through this and update the data without creating a whole new table which uses up newlines etc. Simply stated, a "refresh".

Is there a shell command which deletes the last output and replaces it?

Comment: if you want a quick hack, just insert 100 x blank lines before each print...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to move the cursor around in the terminal. Unfortunately, there isn't a simple, portable way to do that. But one way to do it that works in Linux / Unix is to use [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). IIRC, Windows can also use such sequences, but they are disabled by default.

Anyway, here's a little demo script. Note that this script *might* not be totally portable to all *nix systems, depending on the exact details of the terminal(s) they use ; but I'll let the Unix terminal experts supply corrections. :)

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Simple demo of using ANSI escape codes to move the cursor '''

import sys
from time import sleep
from string import ascii_letters

#ANSI Control Sequence Introducer
csi = '\x1b['

def put(s): sys.stdout.write(s)

#Build a simple table row
def row(c, m, n):
    return '| ' + ' | '.join(n * [m*c]) + ' |'


def main():
    #Some data to make a table with
    data = ascii_letters

    #The number of rows per table section
    numrows = 6

    #Adjust data length to a multiple of numrows
    newlen = (len(data) // numrows) * numrows
    data = data[:newlen]

    m, n = 5, 7
    width = (m + 3) * n + 4

    print 'Table'.center(width, '-')
    for i, c in enumerate(data):
        if i and not i % numrows:
            sleep(2)
            #Move cursor up by numrows
            put('%s%dA' % (csi, numrows)) 
        print "%2d %s" % (i, row(c, m, n))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: well nice one. also to achieve something similar, I'd use `subprocess` to call `watch -n 1 cat result.txt` and just update/write the prettytable result to this file. however, like you mentioned, this just isn't portable. But nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution will be printing blank lines before each `print x`, something like this:

```
def promote(self):
    x = PrettyTable(["Bot ID", "Bot Name"])
    x.align["Bot ID"] = "l" # Left align city names
    x.padding_width = 1 # One space between column edges and contents (default)


    for bot_id, atts in self.bots.iteritems():               
            x.add_row([str(bot_id),atts['screenname']])
    print '\n' * 1000 # as long as it clears the page text
    print x
```

If you absolutely prefer a shell command, you can alternatively write your **prettytable** result in a file, and call `subprocess` and monitor it using `watch` like this:

```
import subprocess
...
# instead of print x, write to a file
with open('result.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(x)
...
# on main()
...
subprocess.call("watch -n 1 cat result.txt", shell=True)
...
```

Personally I don't like this approach though.